# Rails 3.1 select can have object as value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possibel to give select a complete Object as value.

Code:

Models
app/models/pc.rb

```
class Pc < Device
  has_many :gendevs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gendevs, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? },:allow_destroy => true
end
```

app/models/gendev.rb

```
class Gendev < Device
  belongs_to :pc
end
```

(Gendevs are something like scanners, cardreaders etc).
Given Gendevs are available in Database, I wanna have a nested select, giving me the attributes of an object.

View:

app/views/pcs/_form.html.erb

```
....
<% f.fields_for :gendevs do |gdbuilder| %>
<%= gdbuilder.select :gendevs, @gendevs.map { |g| [g.name + '/' + g.kind,g] } %>
<% end %>
```

This is not working, so my question is, how can i do this. Is there a way to serialize the params of g, or how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use g.id instead of g.

```
<% f.fields_for :gendevs do |gdbuilder| %>
<%= gdbuilder.select :gendevs, @gendevs.collect { |g| [g.name + '/' + g.kind, g.id] } %>
<% end %>
```